# Relate DB id's Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, relate

I would like to know how can I relate 2 id's. One frome users table and another from stats table. The id from users is AI , Primary and I want to relate the other id to this one.
I tried Foreign key constraint (INNODB) and it gave me this error #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`game`.`#sql-3de_34f`, CONSTRAINT `?sql?3de_34f_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)) .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

Then run query to add your key, and after that...

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have USER_IDs in your "stats" table that are not in your "users" table.

Delete them if you think they are not useful anymore.

```
DELETE FROM stats where user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id from users);
```

Then, you can create your reference keys.